# Are the names of the zugot disclosed to us in other masechtot?

Tags: mishna, pirke-avot-ethicsof, tannaim

Am I correct in saying that the identities of the *zugot* are only revealed to us within masechet [Pirkei Avot](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1?lang=bi)?

Or are the names of the *zugot* also disclosed to us in other masechtot of the Mishnah? If so, which masechtot of the Mishnah?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean?  Of course the zugot are identified elsewhere.  For example, Shemaya and Avtalyon are mentioned together in Eduyot 5:6, Yoma 35b, Gittin 57b, Pesachim 66a, and other places.

All five zugot are mentioned together in Chagigah 16a:

> Mishnah: [Yossi] ben Yoezer says not to lean [on the chagigah offering]; Yosef ben Yochanan says to lean. Yehoshua ben Perachia says not to lean; Nitai the Arbelite says to lean. Yehudah ben Tabbai says not to lean; Shimon ben Shetach says to lean. Shemai'ah says to lean; Avtaliyon says not to lean. Hillel and Menachem did not argue. Menachem exited, Shammai entered. Shammai says not to lean, Hillel says to lean.

Addendum in Chagigah 16b:

> הָרִאשׁוֹנִים הָיוּ נְשִׂיאִים וּשְׁנִיִּים לָהֶם אֲבוֹת בֵּית דִּין: -- The first ones [mentioned of the pair] were Princes (nasiim) and their seconds were heads of the court (avot bet din).

Comment: I meant are they listed anywhere else as zugot, in the Mishnah?

Comment: You are interested in the use of the word "zugot" to refer to the 2 top sages?  I only see the word used in that sense in Mishnah Peah 2:6.

Comment: The mishna in Chagiga pretty much spells it out, just without the word "zugot" per se. It lists successive pairs of rabbis.